# Profiling tools for Android NDK app

Tags: android, c++, profiling

I want to profile C++ algorithms in Android NDK application.

Looking for good profiler tool.

Tool should not require any particular SDK (Android Studio or Eclipse) and should be as portable as possible. Because my C++ libraries can be used with Qt and Xamarin apps as well.

I am currently considering https://github.com/richq/android-ndk-profiler
Is it any good? What are the alternatives?

Comment: While you're looking, [*try this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771).

Answer (score 1):

Our [C++ Profiler](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Profilers/index.html) might meet your needs.

It is independent of specific SDKs and can thus be used in a variety of development environments, including embedded and workstation contexts.

It gains its SDK/environment independence by requiring that you customize its data collection runtime component to be compatible with that environment.  This usually takes a few lines of code, once.

It will run out of the box with GCC4 for plain C++ compiles on Windows, using its off-the-shelf data collection component.